# How to assign the result of a shell command to a MySQL variable?

Tags: mysql, shell, variables

Shell command inside **MySQL shell** returns value:

```
mysql> \! echo 1
1
```

How to assign this result to MySQL variable? Like:

```
mysql> set @var = \! echo 1
1
    -> ;
```

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1**

Comment: `set @var = (SELECT 1);`, `set @var = 1`, there is no other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `SET` is a server command, which changes the state of variables held on the server; whereas `system` (and its `\!` shorthand) is a client command, which forks a process on the client.  Whilst it could be possible for the client to transmit the forked process's exit code to the server for storage in a user variable, I don't think the MySQL command line client offers this functionality.

From [`mysql-5.5.29/client/mysql.cc`](http://fossies.org/dox/mysql-5.5.29/mysql_8cc_source.html#l03958):

```
3958: static int
3959: com_shell(String *buffer __attribute__((unused)),
3960:           char *line __attribute__((unused)))
3961: {
3962:   char *shell_cmd;
3963: 
3964:   /* Skip space from line begin */
3965:   while (my_isspace(charset_info, *line))
3966:     line++;
3967:   if (!(shell_cmd = strchr(line, ' ')))
3968:   {
3969:     put_info("Usage: \\! shell-command", INFO_ERROR);
3970:     return -1;
3971:   }
3972:   /*
3973:     The output of the shell command does not
3974:     get directed to the pager or the outfile
3975:   */
3976:   if (system(shell_cmd) == -1)
3977:   {
3978:     put_info(strerror(errno), INFO_ERROR, errno);
3979:     return -1;
3980:   }
3981:   return 0;
3982: }
```

Note in particular that the return value of the `system(3)` call is not stored anywhere; however the `com_shell()` function call will return `-1` if the process exited with that code.

Comment: @Yuriy: If you want to run the process on the server, you could consider using a [UDF](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/) that would enable you to do something like `SET @var := sys_eval('/bin/echo 1')` (but note the very serious security caveats).